# clear a bitmap from arraytlist using recycle not working, ANDROID

Tags: java, android, arraylist, bitmap, recycle

I created an arraylist for bitmaps and then i want to remove a single bitmap from arraylist when a button is clicked. I used this for clearing bitmap

```
DELETE.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            bitmapArray.get(0).recycle();

        }
    });
```

But this doesnt seem to work . it does not remove the bitmap. Please suggest me something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `bitmapArray.remove(0);` after `bitmapArray.get(0).recycle();`

Answer (score 2):

Add this line after..

```
bitmapArray.get(0).recycle();
```

you are just recycling but not removing the bitmap object from the list..

```
bitmapArray.remove(0);
```